# Notice: Undefined index after migration from magento 1.7.0.2 to magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, php, exception

Notice: Undefined index:  in /home/tbnet/public_html/m2.3/vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php on line 70

how to solve this error? cannot access m2.3.4 backend

Comment: did you run all commands like upgrade, compile etc?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check your core_config_data table.

If there is a path with value = dev/front_end_development_workflow/type, delete it.

Hope it helps!